# How to calculate running total from an array object in Javascript/Typescript and display output at every instance using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript

I am working on a MEAN stack project and have an array that looks like this:

```
savings: any = [300, 450, 350, 500]
```

I also have a variable called savings_bf, which is savings brought forward retrieved from a DB with the value below.

```
savings_bf = 15000
```

I would like to write some code with typescript to get the running total, factor in the savings_bf into the calculation,and display the output with HTML.

As i have stated, this is for a MEAN stack application using Typescript 3.5.3. The output works as expected on the console, but the problem is replicating the output on the front-end.

The code i have so far is:

```js
this._savings_total = +this.savings.reduce((result, a) => {
            var savings_amount = a.savings_amount;
            return result + savings_amount;
          }, this.savings_bf);
```

,and displaying the output in html as;

```html
<p>{{_savings_amount}}</p>
```

The expected HTML output should be:

```
15300,15750,16100,16600,
but the actual output is the final value 16600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you're overriding value of this_savings_bf in each iteration, You should simply map through the values and use a variable to keep track of last add value

```js
let savings = [300, 450, 350, 500]
let savings_bf = 15000
let temp = savings_bf

let final = savings.map(v => temp += v)

console.log(final)
```

Or you can simply use forEach build html string in each iteration and at the end of loop add to desired place

```js
let savings = [300, 450, 350, 500]
let savings_bf = 15000 
let html = ''

savings.forEach(v=>{
  savings_bf += v
  html += `<p>${savings_bf}</p>`
})

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id='test'/>
```

---

> What if i intend for my output to begin with the initial value of
>   savings_bf

```js
let savings = [300, 450, 350, 500]
let savings_bf = 15000
let html = ''

savings.forEach(v => {
  html += `<p>${savings_bf}</p>`
  savings_bf += v
})

html += `<p>${savings_bf}</p>`

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id='test' />
```

Comment: What if i intend for my output to begin with the initial value of savings_bf, as [15000,15300,15750,16100,16600]

Comment: @SteveGaita you can after you do addition after "html += `<p>${savings_bf}</p>`"

Comment: @SteveGaita see the last snippet