# How to properly push a new object with multiple element into an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript

I am attempting to push a newly generated object into an array in JavaScript

I  have an array of the form:

```
savings: any = [{month: "January", amount: 300}, {month: "February",  amount:450}, {month: "March", amount: 500}]
```

and a variable called **savings_bf** with the value;

```
savings_bf = 15000
```

I used both the **amount** values from the array **savings** and the **savings_bf** to calculate running total using the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737436/11849137 to get the output:

```
_total_cf = [15300,15750,16250]
```

my code looks as follows;

```
savings.forEach(s =>s.total_cf = _total_cf)
```

The expected output for the new **savings** array should be:

```
[{month: "January", amount: 300, total_cf: 15300 }, {month: "February",  amount:450, total_cf: 15750}, {month: "March", amount: 500 total_cf: 16250}]
```

actual output:

```
[{month: "January", amount: 300, total_cf: [15300,15750,16250]}, {month: "February",  amount:450, total_cf: [15300,15750,16250]}, {month: "March", amount: 500 total_cf: [15300,15750,16250]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `.map()` the array, adding the running total you update during the loop.

```js
const months = [
  {month: "January", amount: 300},
  {month: "February",  amount:450},
  {month: "March", amount: 500}
];
const savings = 15000;
let running_total = savings;
const updated_months = months.map( item => {
  running_total += item.amount;
  return {
    month: item.month,
    amount: running_total
  };
});
console.log( updated_months );
```

If for some reason you need the `_total_cf` variable for something else as well, you can easily extract it again:

```js
const updated_months = [
  {month: "January", amount: 15300},
  {month: "February",  amount:15750},
  {month: "March", amount: 16250}
];

const _total_cf = updated_months.map( item => item.amount );

console.log( _total_cf );
```

Comment: Related to this.What if i want the first value of _total_cf to the initial value of _saving_bf = 15000, to get an output of  [15000,15300, 15750, 16250]

Comment: Just add it in front of the array by spreading _total_cf?  `const series = [ _saving_bf , ..._total_cf ]` Or `Array.unshift( 15000 )` to push it to the start of the array? There's a lot of possibilities, but which one is most appropriate kind of depends on the rest of the code and your style preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use second parameter of callback method provided to `forEach` to keep track of the index. Since `_total_cf` is an array, you need to access proper item based on index. You can use index in the callback as following:

```js
var savings = [{month: "January", amount: 300}, {month: "February",  amount:450}, {month: "March", amount: 500}]

var _total_cf = [15300,15750,16250];

savings.forEach((s, index) => s.total_cf = _total_cf[index]) ;

console.log(savings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to do map each object in the array and use the *index* it provides in the callback (second parameter) to get the corresponding element from the `_total_cf` array.

Also use the spread operator `...` to do a merge with the previous object properties and the new one from the `_total_cf` array:

```js
const savings = [{month: "January", amount: 300}, {month: "February",  amount:450}, {month: "March", amount: 500}];

const _total_cf = [15300,15750,16250];

const result = savings.map((obj, idx) => ({...obj, total_cf: _total_cf[idx]}));

console.log(result);
```

In your code you are assigning the entire `total_cf` array to the `total_cf` property you create in each iteration.

```
//the entire array is assigned to the `total_cf` property.
savings.forEach(s =>s.total_cf = _total_cf);
```

Also you are mutating the original objects in the `savings` array in the `forEach`. In the `map` operation the a new array is returned with new objects in it, having the old props plus the new property you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  You can use following code.
savings.forEach((item, index, array) => {
    savings[index].total_cf = _total_cf[index];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the right approach to calculate your savings_bf and you can simply do all at once.

```
    var savings = [{month: "January", amount: 300}, {month: "February",  amount:450}, {month: "March", amount: 500}];
    var savings_bf = 15000 ;
   savings.forEach(function(val) {
  //  console.log(val);
val['savings_bf'] = parseInt(savings_bf)+val['amount'];
});
    console.log(savings);
```

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I have updated the code with javascript .

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce also to calculate the total_cf

try the following code

```
const savings = [
  {month: "January", amount: 300},
  {month: "February",  amount:450},
  {month: "March", amount: 500}
];
const savings_bf = 15000;

savings.reduce((a,b)=>{
    b.total_cf = (a[a.length-1] ? a[a.length-1].total_cf : savings_bf) + b.amount 
    a.push(b)
    return a
},[])
```